# Callback Functions using Timers in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-class

I am working on a statistical model of a content distribution server in MATLAB and have decided to use OO programming. This is my first foray into OO with MATLAB and I have hit a snag. I am attempting to model a download connection to the server, at the moment it is just a MATLAB timer and a boolean. When the timer expires I want to set the `isActive` field from `true` to `false`. So quite simple I feel but then I have been battling with this for more then a day now. Below is the code for the class so far:

```
    classdef dl<handle
        properties
            isActive = true
            ttl = 0
        end
        methods
            function this = startTimer(this, varargin)
                this.ttl = timer('TimerFcn', @()killConnection(this), 'StartDelay',1);     
                start(this.ttl);            
            end
        end

        methods (Access = private)
            function obj = killConnection(obj, varargin)
                obj.isActive = false;
            end        
        end
    end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem I was having, the issue was in the way the callback handler was declared. Im not sure if the precise reason but there is a better explanation here if anyone is interested, see this blog post http://syncor.blogspot.com/2011/01/matlabusing-callbacks-in-classdef.html.

Here are the changes I made to get successful operation. Firstly i changed the callback function into the proper structure for the callback:

```
    function killConnection(event, string_arg, this)
```

Then I declared the callback differently in the timer:

```
    this.ttl = timer('TimerFcn', {@dl.killConnection, this}, 'StartDelay',1);
```

This worked for me. Thanks for the help it was really getting to me :P.

Comment: I didn't understand what is `dl` in your code, but I played with it and managed to make it work. Thanks for this clue: `{<handle>}` (see my answer). BTW, the solution from the link works only with Static methods.

Answer (score 1):

My guess without trying it, is that the callback needs to be a static class function and the argument list needs to be with the proper parameters for a timer. The static class callback would then need to locate the object reference to set the instance `isActive` flag. `findobj` might get the class object instance by name since you chose to use a handle object but that could affect the real-time response.

```
this.ttl = timer('TimerFcn', @dl.killConnection, 'StartDelay',1); 


methods(Static)
      function killConnection(obj, event, string_arg)
        ...
      end
end
```

Just a guess. Good luck, I'm interested in the real answer since I had been thinking about trying this just recently.

Comment: I tried what you suggested out with no luck. I get a "Undefined function or method 'dl.killConnection' for input arguments of type 'timer'" error back. Which is the same issue I have been having, I cant get it to recognize the function i want to use as a callback.

Answer (score 0):

---- TimerHandle.m ---------

```
classdef TimerHandle < handle    
    properties
        replay_timer
        count = 0
    end
    methods
        function register_timer(obj)
            obj.replay_timer = timer('TimerFcn', {@obj.on_timer}, 'ExecutionMode', 'fixedSpacing', ...
                'Period', 1, 'BusyMode', 'drop', 'TasksToExecute', inf);
        end
        function on_timer(obj, varargin)
            obj.count = obj.count + 1;
            fprintf('[%d] on_timer()\n', obj.count);
        end
        function delete(obj)
            delete(obj.replay_timer);
            obj.delete@handle();
        end
    end
end
```

Usage:

```
>> th = TimerHandle;
>> th.register_timer
>> start(th.replay_timer)
[1] on_timer()
[2] on_timer()
[3] on_timer()
[4] on_timer()
[5] on_timer()
[6] on_timer()
[7] on_timer()
[8] on_timer()
[9] on_timer()
>> stop(th.replay_timer)
>> delete(th)
```